# Display all cars older than 5 years

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am new at MongoDB, I have about 5 documents about cars, I need to display all cars older than 5 years. How would I do that?

Each document looks similar to this

```
{
    "Model" :2005,
    "Make" : "Ford fiesta",
    "Owner" :"A Smith",
    "RegistrationNumber" :"ABC 234 GP",
    "address" :"21 Maureen street, Pretoria, South Africa"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`db.<Table_Name_Here>.find({ "Model": {$lt : 2015} })`